# Filtering a list based on a string of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists (names list, and paths list) and I want to use them to create a third list whose elements are the paths that contains no names from the name list:

```
names = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5']
paths = ['dataset/name_1/00000003.jpg',
         'dataset/name_2/00000001.jpg', 
         'dataset/name_3/00000000.png', 
         'dataset/name_4/00000002.jpg',
         'dataset/name_5/00000000.jpg', 
         'dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
```

The resultant list from the above two lists should be

```
['dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
```

I achieved this by:

```
check = []
for path in paths:
    exist_boolean = any([path.__contains__(x) for  x in names])
    check.append(exist_boolean)

check_final = [not i for i in check] 
list(compress(paths, check_final))
```

This is an overkill, is there an elegant way of doing than the ugly logic I came up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
[x for x in paths if all(y not in x for y in names)]
```

**Code**:

```
names = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5']
paths = ['dataset/name_1/00000003.jpg',
         'dataset/name_2/00000001.jpg', 
         'dataset/name_3/00000000.png', 
         'dataset/name_4/00000002.jpg',
         'dataset/name_5/00000000.jpg', 
         'dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']

list3 = [x for x in paths if all(y not in x for y in names)]
# ['dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it :)

```
names = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5']
paths = ['dataset/name_1/00000003.jpg',
         'dataset/name_2/00000001.jpg',
         'dataset/name_3/00000000.png',
         'dataset/name_4/00000002.jpg',
         'dataset/name_5/00000000.jpg',
         'dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
newpath = paths
nopath = []
for path in paths:
    for name in names:
        if name in path:
            nopath.append(path)

for path in nopath:
    newpath.remove(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `any` function here; with list comprehension:-

```
>>> names = ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', 'name_5']
>>> paths = ['dataset/name_1/00000003.jpg',
...          'dataset/name_2/00000001.jpg', 
...          'dataset/name_3/00000000.png', 
...          'dataset/name_4/00000002.jpg',
...          'dataset/name_5/00000000.jpg', 
...          'dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
>>> 
>>> [ j for j in paths if not any(n in j for n in names)]
['dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna try one of following

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(?!.*({}))'.format("|".join(names)))
list3 = list(filter(regex.search, paths))
# ['dataset/name_6/00000002.jpg']

# Perform test performance in list names 10k items and 15k items in paths
In[1]: %timeit list(filter(regex.search, paths))
15 ms ± 314 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit [x for x in paths if all(y not in x for y in names)]
41.4 ms ± 903 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```